# Double Hurdle model with continuous DV and two sources of zeros

Tags: r, multiple-regression, continuous-data, zero-inflation

I want to regress a data set that contains a lot of zero's (~55%) and is determined by a typical 2-stage decision process generating the zeros:

1. Consumer decides to apply for a bank loan or not (0-1)
2. Bank grants application or not (0-Inf; on a continuous scale)

Based on the research I conducted so far I am pretty certain that the double hurdle model proposed by Cragg (or a version of it) is a promising approach for my regression. 
(Research includes e.g., Frees, E. W. Regression Modeling with Actuarial and Financial Applications 2011; Cragg, J. G. Some Statistical Models for Limited Dependent Variables with Application to the Demand for Durable Goods Econometrica, 1971; Smith, On Dependency in Double-Hurdle Models, 1998 (available at: https://core.ac.uk/download/files/454/12162575.pdf); Vignette of the mhurdle package in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mhurdle/vignettes/mhurdle.pdf)

With the mhurdle package in R this would suggest a regression as follows:

```
hurd <- function (x,y) {
         mhurdle(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 | IV2 + IV3 | 0,
                 data = xx, dist = x, corr = y)
}
# with x being "n" for normal, "ln" for log-normal, "tn" for truncated-normal" and y being "i" for independent or "d" for dependent
```

I am though still struggeling to determine the following two things with required certainty - maybe someone is able to help me with this:

- Double Hurdle models (also the ones proposed by Cragg) are reguarly referenced in the context of count DV - are those models appropriate to handle a continuous DV as well? Are there any specific modifications required? (the mhurdle package e.g., suggests that it is possible)
- Zero-inflation models (that are though only applicable to count data) can generally handle two sources of zeros. Are double hurdle models also capable of handling zeros arising from both hurdles? (the vignette of the mhurdle package implies that the Cragg DH model with a "normal" distribution accounts for that)

Thanks a lot,
Jan